# Read rows of .NET System.Data.DataTable in Matlab

Tags: c#, .net, windows, matlab, datatable

I have used a .NET framework library in MATLAB 2018b to do certain tasks which return me at the end a simple **System.Data.DataTable** object. I am wondering how I can read a single row of the file, or even print it to a .csv file, or something like that. I am not able to do anything with the returned DataTable.

This is the output of the returned DataTable:

```
retdata = 

  DataTable[] with properties:

            Length: 1
        LongLength: 1
              Rank: 1
          SyncRoot: [1×1 System.Data.DataTable[]]
        IsReadOnly: 0
       IsFixedSize: 1
    IsSynchronized: 0
```

The only thing that I could investigate about this returned object is this:

```
>> retdata(1)

ans = 

  DataTable with properties:

         CaseSensitive: 0
         IsInitialized: 1
        RemotingFormat: Xml
        ChildRelations: [1×1 System.Data.DataRelationCollection+DataTableRelationCollection]
               Columns: [1×1 System.Data.DataColumnCollection]
           Constraints: [1×1 System.Data.ConstraintCollection]
               DataSet: [1×1 System.Data.DataSet]
           DefaultView: [1×1 System.Data.DataView]
     DisplayExpression: [1×1 System.String]
    ExtendedProperties: [1×1 System.Data.PropertyCollection]
             HasErrors: 0
                Locale: [1×1 System.Globalization.CultureInfo]
       MinimumCapacity: 50
       ParentRelations: [1×1 System.Data.DataRelationCollection+DataTableRelationCollection]
            PrimaryKey: [1×1 System.Data.DataColumn[]]
                  Rows: [1×1 System.Data.DataRowCollection]
             TableName: [1×1 System.String]
             Namespace: [1×1 System.String]
                Prefix: [1×1 System.String]
                  Site: []
             Container: []
            DesignMode: 0
```

I have a C# code which uses `retdata[0].Rows[i]["Start Date"]` to read rows of data in a *for* loop. I want to do the same thing with MATLAB. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to continue? Looks like you already learned that matlab uses () and 1 based indexing. Should be something like `Rows(i+1)`.

Comment: When I follow your advise I get the error: `Array formation and indexing are not allowed on .NET objects.  Use Set and Get methods to access .NET array elements.`

Comment: The rows of the table are being sent to matlab as an item array.  So there are three methods that may work in matlab : dlmread, readtable, readmatrix.

Comment: I had issue a few years ago with matlab that I was reading a matrix from a file and the file contains a blank row at the end.  The matrix methods would not work.  What we eventually did was read the entire file a a string.  Then parse the rows of the string using "N - 1" rows.  Matlab matrix methods only allows the entire matrix to be read.  String methods allow a parameter N to be used.  So sometimes you have to read a matrix one row at a time using string methods and then parse the string into fields.

Comment: @jdweng I tried it with different methods but it didn't work. It is not a pure Matlab table but a .NET data.

Comment: What error do you get?  I would try passing as dt.AsEnumerable() instead of the entire table which will pass an array of rows instead of the entire table.

Comment: @jdweng So what I did is that I called `import System.Data.DataSetExtensions.*` and then I executed `b = DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(retdata(1))` and finally I got an Enumerator with `c = b.GetEnumerator();`. However, I can't still read a row with conventional matlab commands: `dlmread(c)`. Because it says `Filename must be a character vector or string scalar.`. And the _c_ is `Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__97<System*Data*DataRow> with properties:     <>3__source: [1×1 System.Data.DataRowCollection]`

Comment: Strings in Matlab are like c language.  Strings are byte arrays terminate with '\0'.  In c# characters are a class with one or two bytes.